# sorting a list, preserving the grouped character

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a list "messages"

```
  recei | sender |date(timestamp)| id
--------+--------+---------------+----
 Nickel | Lisett |   3.10.1991   | 1
  Tom   | Nickel |   4.12.1991   | 2
 Lisett | Nickel |   03.9.1991   | 3
 Nickel | Lisett |   01.9.1991   | 4
  Tom   | Nickel |   15.9.1991   | 5
 Nickel |  Tom   |   2.10.1991   | 6
```

When I do this sql-query:

```
SELECT *, IF(recei='Nickel', sender, recei ) AS name
FROM messages WHERE recei='Nickel' OR sender='Nickel'
ORDER BY name, date;
```

I get the following Result

```
           name           |  recei | sender |  date   |id
 (=interlocutor of Nickel)|        |        |         |
--------------------------+--------+--------+---------+----
           Lisett         | Nickel | Lisett |3.10.1991| 1
           Lisett         | Lisett | Nickel |03.9.1991| 3
           Lisett         | Nickel | Lisett |01.9.1991| 4
           Tom            |   Tom  | Nickel |4.12.1991| 2
           Tom            |   Tom  | Nickel |15.9.1991| 5
           Tom            | Nickel |  Tom   |2.10.1991| 6
```

But I would like to get the last interlocutor of Nickel on Top of the List: So I would like to order the Groups "Lisett" (the lines with the name (Interlocutor) Lisett) and "Tom" by the earliest date. In this special case put the Group "Tom" above the group "Lisett". So to say look for the earliest date inside the groups and put the group with the earlier date above the other one. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an inner join for get the  date_max and use this column for sort

```
SELECT a.* , IF(a.recei='Nickel', a.sender, a.recei ) AS name
FROM messages as a 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT  IF(recei='Nickel', sender, recei ) as name, max(date) date_max
      FROM messages WHERE recei='Nickel' OR sender='Nickel'
      group by name ) t on t.name = IF(a.recei='Nickel', a.sender, a.recei )
WHERE a.recei='Nickel' OR a.sender='Nickel'
ORDER BY t.date_max, name, a.date
```

Comment: there seems to be some mistake in the code but I can't find it. I get several error messages when I run the code inside phpmyAdmin. Among them is

an expression was expected. (near "IF" at position 10)

Comment: sorry but the code is still not working :( same error messages

Comment: When I execute your (updated) code I get the following error message:

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the a.messages

static analysis:

19 errors were found:

SQL-Befehl: Dokumentation %%documentation

SELECT a.messages.* , IF(a.recei='Nickel', a.sender, a.recei ) AS name FROM messages as a INNER JOIN ( SELECT IF(recei='Nickel', sender, recei ) as name, max(date) date_max FROM messages WHERE recei='Nickel' OR sender='Nickel' group by name ) t on t.name = a.name WHERE a.recei='Nickel' OR a.sender='Nickel' ORDER BY t.date_max, a.name, a.date LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL meldet %%prompts: Dokumentation

#1051 - Unknown table 'a.messages'

Comment: when I modify the code to

SELECT * , IF(recei='Nickel', sender, recei ) AS name
FROM messages AS a
INNER JOIN ( SELECT  IF(recei='Nickel', sender, recei ) as namee, max(date) date_max
      FROM messages WHERE recei='Nickel' OR sender='Nickel'
      group by namee ) t on namee = IF(recei='Nickel', sender, recei )
WHERE recei='Nickel' OR sender='Nickel'
ORDER BY date_max, name, date

it seems to work. As soon as I put a a.name into line 5  it it doesnt work anymore why is this? Maybe a problem with my phpmyadmin?

Comment: i have update the answer changing (wrong)  a.messages.*   in a.* .. let me know

Comment: now I have:

MySQL meldet: Dokumentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'a.name' in 'on clause'

Comment: correct the use of alias for calculated  column  in where  ( same as ON ) is not allowed .. i have changed  the answer  with the full code for name

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'a.name' in 'order clause'

Comment: I have a few Questions: Is the MAX() function working for fields with timestamp and is it possible that two fields with a timestamp have the same time? If so what habbens then with the MAX() function? Furthermore what does the a.* do? And can I replace "INNER JOIN" with "JOIN" because this improves the request-time for 1ms. Thanks for your help anyway the code works now!